# Is it imperative that I change Label to Control to avoid a possible runtime error?

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error, resharper

In trying to purify an inherited legacy VB.NET / ASP project, I'm resharperizing it, and it tells me, "﻿*Runtime errors might occur when converting 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'*" on this line:

```
Dim _UserNameLabel As Label = PortalLogin.FindControl("UserNameLabel")
```

...but when I acquiesce and let it change it to this:

```
Dim _UserNameLabel As Control = PortalLogin.FindControl("UserNameLabel")
```

...the "Style" property here reds up:

```
_UserNameLabel.Style("color") = dt1.Rows(0)("TextBoxColor")
```

Is there an alternate way to supply that Label/Control a color, am I better off ignoring Resharper's suggestion, or what?

Comment: Neither one will compile with `Option Strict On`.  FindControl returns a Control and `Style` is not a property of Control.  Cast the return to label.

Comment: The most purification would come from turning Option Strict On.  It might help solve The Other Mysteries

Comment: Options > Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults > Option Explicit is already On; Option Strict is Off, though... Option Infer, whatever that is, is On, and finally Option Compare is Binary.

Comment: Those are the defaults for new projects.  **Project Properties --> Compile --> Option Strict On**  Always on.  Tune it in and rip off the knob.  It will prevent you from compiling using implicit conversions (first scenario in your Q) and when using late binding (second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct option is:

```
Dim _UserNameLabel = DirectCast(PortalLogin.FindControl("UserNameLabel"), Label)
```

The `Control` reference returned by `FindControl` is cast as type `Label` and you can then access members specific to type `Label`.  It is `Option Infer On` that allows the type of the `UserNameLabel` variable to be inferred from its initialising expression.  With `Option Infer Off` you would need to write:

```
Dim _UserNameLabel As Label = DirectCast(PortalLogin.FindControl("UserNameLabel"), Label)
```

Some people prefer to do that anyway, for clarity.  Type inference is often handy but not required.  Where it is required is in using anonymous types returned by LINQ queries.

Comment: Why is DirectCast() preferred to CType(), which is what Resharper uses?

Comment: `DirectCast` is a genuine cast. `CType` is a conversion. If the object is already the target type then no conversion is necessary, so there's no point using a conversion function that incorporates type checking for the purpose.

Comment: Good to know; hopefully the Resharperers are listening.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether ReSharper can know that the object is the type it's being cast as or whether a conversion might be required.  I've never actually encountered that from ReSharper because I had `Option Strict On` long before I started using ReSharper, so I've always added required casts myself without thinking, and I actually don't write much VB code these days anyway.